# helpText shown with extra lines (R Shiny)

Tags: r, shiny

When I use the following codes, there is a line between each of them. Please see the image attached. [image]

```
CODE:

 helpText("method 1 = TwoStepCluster (Complete)"),
 helpText("method 2 = TwoStepCluster (Ward.D2)"),
 helpText("method 3 = TwoStepCluster (none)"),
 helpText("method 4 = Fixed Solution used as a starting point"),
```

How can I make the results shown with no additional lines?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is showing adding additional line because you are using multiple `helpText`. You just need to use one `helpText` and multiple line break `br()` to get your desired results:

```
helpText("method 1 = TwoStepCluster (Complete)", 
           br(),
          "method 2 = TwoStepCluster (Ward.D2)",
           br(),
          "method 3 = TwoStepCluster (none)",
           br(),
          "method 4 = Fixed Solution used as a starting point")
```

**Result:**

[image]